# Laravel 4: "Replace" Eloquent instead of "Select"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to use the SQL function replace to replace the ID if it exist in the database (users_id). How can I use it with Eloquent. I tried using the documentation provided in four.laravel.com. But could still not figure it out. Everytime i try to "update" the users information it will create a new record with the same ID

**Controller**

```
        public function getUserInformation() {
            $user_zip_codes = DB::table('users')
                    ->join('zip_codes', 'zip_code', '=', 'user_zip_code')
                    ->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
            $userdata = array(
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'first_name' => Input::get('first_name'),
            'last_name' => Input::get('last_name'),
            'street_1' => Input::get('street_1'),  
            'street_2' => Input::get('street_2'),  
            'apartment' => Input::get('apartment'),
            'street_2' => Input::get('street_2'),  
            'apartment' => Input::get('apartment'),
            'user_zip_code' => $user_zip_codes->zip_code,
            'city' => $user_zip_codes->city,
            'state' => 'Alabama'
            );
            $user = new UsersInformation($userdata);
            $user->save();

            return Redirect::to('dashboard');
    }
```

If you need additional code let me know! Thanks!

Comment: i'm not laravel user,however ,i understand that you use a fixed id of the authentified user,you create the user and you save,i think you must first find the user with his id and then modifie his informations , and save ?

Comment: Yeah, I think thats the part I am needing help with..           $user = new UsersInformation($userdata);
            $user->save();..should be updating...not using Insert.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to call update method not save like in docs :

Laravel docs:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#insert-update-delete

```
    public function getUserInformation() {
        $user_zip_codes = DB::table('users')
                ->join('zip_codes', 'zip_code', '=', 'user_zip_code')
                ->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
        Auth::user()->update(array(
        'first_name' => Input::get('first_name'),
        'last_name' => Input::get('last_name'),
        'street_1' => Input::get('street_1'),  
        'street_2' => Input::get('street_2'),  
        'apartment' => Input::get('apartment'),
        'street_2' => Input::get('street_2'),  
        'apartment' => Input::get('apartment'),
        'user_zip_code' => $user_zip_codes->zip_code,
        'city' => $user_zip_codes->city,
        'state' => 'Alabama'
        ));
        return Redirect::to('dashboard');
}
```